# Using depth=n in wp_list_pages

Tags: functions, wp-list-pages

I'm wondering what is the proper way to use depth n in wp_list_pages. I currently have a menu in my sidebar that goes 4 levels deep but I'd like to prevent levels 3 & 4 from displaying.

The codex says:

> **'depth'**
>
> (int) Number of levels in the hierarchy of pages to include in the generated list. Accepts -1 (any depth), 0 (all pages), 1 (top-level pages only), ***and n (pages to the given n depth)***. Default 0.

I've tried:

```
wp_list_pages('child_of=124&title_li&depth=n(2)')
wp_list_pages('child_of=124&title_li&depth=n2')
```

I can't seem to find any examples on how to use depth in this instance.

Comment: `depth=n2` should be `depth=2`

Comment: `n` is just a "placeholder" and should be replaced by the actual integer value

Comment: Thanks...I guess I was thinking like css with nth-child().

Comment: My pleasure, enjoy ;-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen as an answer please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`depth=n2` should be `depth=2`. `n` is just a "placeholder" and should be replaced by the actual integer value of your choice